# update product quantity in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

how to update downloadable product quantity in shopping cart in magento thuough php

```
$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($p_id);      
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();      
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct($_product);           
$quote->updateItem($item->getId(), array( 'qty' => $p_qty)); getCart()->save();
```

Comment: Is this a question ?

Comment: yes, i m unable to increase or decrease the quantity of product in shopping cart item in magento 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$quoteId = 1251; 
$productItem['qty'] = 2;
$productId =  17;
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);
$quote   = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quoteId);
$quoteItem = $quote->getItemByProduct($product); 

if ($productItem['qty'] > 0) {
    $quoteItem->setQty($productItem['qty']);
}
try {
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: not work plz update codes.   $quoteItem = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);  after that line exception occcur in php

Comment: what is issues are facing?

Comment: according to customer login, i have to change product quantity in cart but not success . Is there having any update method for update quantity and my product has a downladable product which are E-book and Print-book type  contains link

Comment: $quoteItem->setQty($productItem['qty']);   <-- error